# How can i remove ids one by one from querystring in asp.net using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want remove "ids"one by one querystring from my url. How can i do this ? (using Asp.net4.0 , c#)

```
Default.aspx?ids=10,2,6,5
```

I want to remove"ids=6", but language would be the first,middle or last, so I will have this :

```
Default.aspx?ids=10,2,5,
```

Comment: _"but language would be the first,middle or last"_ ??

Comment: Do you want to remove the ids and redirect or remove and use it for processing?

Comment: What is the logic behind removing the 3rd id?

Answer (score 1):

Step 1. Have your ids in an array by:-

```
string[] idsarray = Request.QueryString["ids"].ToString().Split(',');
```

step 2. create a function to remove as per your language

```
string removeidat(string[] id, string at)
{
     string toren = "";
     int remat = -1;
     if (at=="first")
     {
          remat = 0;
     }
     else if (at == "middle")
     {
          remat = id.Length / 2;
     }
     else
     {
          remat = id.GetUpperBound(0);
     }
     for (int i = 0; i < id.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
     {
          if (i!=remat)
          {
               toren += id[i] + ",";
          }
     }
     if (toren.Length>0)
     {
          toren = toren.Substring(0, toren.Length - 1);
     }
     return toren;
}
```

Example : if you want to remove last id your code would be

```
string[] idsarray = Request.QueryString["ids"].ToString().Split(',');
string newids = removeidat(idsarray , "last")
```

Comment: looking this url http://www.snapdeal.com/product/computers-laptops/compare?ids=220366,664953,664952  and remove compare product after looking query string  I want to similar satep this url working thanks.....

Comment: Yoy are too vague . can you say what really you want to achive?

Answer (score 0):

```
string strIDs = Request.QueryString["ids"];
if(strIDs != null)
{
    string[] ids = strIDs.Split(new[]{','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    var no6 = ids.Where(id => id != "6");
    string newUrl = string.Format("Default.aspx?ids={0}", string.Join(",", no6));
    Response.Redirect(newUrl);
}
```